# Testcafe & microsoft authentication fails to redirect during authentication flow

Tags: typescript, authentication, testing, automation, testcafe

So I'm writing a test script for Testcafe for our web application as well as getting familiar with typescript. What I'm doing is basically having a LoginPage.ts, a LandingPage.ts (not relevant for this issue) and a LandingPageTests.ts (which contains the actual tests).

The application has an authentication flow that uses Microsoft login. So, the script clicks on a Microsoft login button from this application, fills out the forms with my email, then inputs the password on the organization page, clicks on Yes for the stay signed in question from the Microsoft login page, then the redirect from https://login.microsoftonline.com/kmsi?sso_reload=true should happen, but the redirect destination refuses this with error code 500 (shown in dev tools).

I asked a developer about this and he said the access token has already been exchanged in the flow, which is weird. He cannot help me any further.

I googled a lot yesterday and today, but topics about this were either closed or not suitable for my approach.

Anyone can point me in the right direction, on how to change the script for the redirect to happen? I'm not an expert in testcafe nor typescript. Below the relevant files, sensitive data is removed. I don't know what, if anything, I'm doing wrong, maybe I picked the wrong career.  :(

LoginPage.ts:

```
import { Selector, t } from 'testcafe';

export default class LoginPage {
    private microsoftButton = Selector('span').withText('MICROSOFT');
    private emailField = Selector('#i0116');
    private nextBtn = Selector('#idSIButton9');
    private passwordField = Selector('#passwordInput');
    private signInBtn = Selector('#submitButton');
    private staySignedIn = Selector('#idSIButton9');


    async login (username : string, password : string){
        await t
            .setTestSpeed(1)
            .click(this.microsoftButton)
            .maximizeWindow()
            .typeText(this.emailField, username, {paste : true})
            .click(this.nextBtn)
            .typeText(this.passwordField, password)
            .click(this.signInBtn)
            .click(this.staySignedIn)
    };
};
```

LoadingPageTests.ts:

```
import LoginPage from './pages/LoginPage';
import LandingPage from './pages/LandingPage';

const loginPage = new LoginPage();
const landingPage = new LandingPage();
const username = 'removed';
const password = 'removed';


fixture`removed Landing page`
  .page`removed`
  .beforeEach(async (t) => {
    await loginPage.login(username, password)

  })
  .afterEach(async (t) => {
    await landingPage.logout()
  });

test(not really relevant as the login part fails)
```

Comment: Let's discus it in the context of the following issue: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4296

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run script like this and it works: `node --max-http-header-size=1024000 ./node_modules/testcafe/bin/testcafe.js chrome <your script`